# Is there a rule in football that caps the amount of transfer money paid by a team for a player?

Tags: rules, football, fifa, transfer

I am just baffled by the way that players like De Bruyne, Sterling etc are costing huge amounts of money for the clubs. I personally don't feel that these players are worth this much. Also Juventus demanding 100€ or more for Pogba is just insane, no doubt he is a great midfielder but  not worth that sum of money.

So is there any rule in Fifa books that caps the amount of transfer money being paid for a player?

Comment: I've removed the bits of this question which were asking for people's opinions as that would make the question off-topic here.

Comment: No there isn't, and no players are not worth the money most of the time. But if Juventus does not want to sell Pogba, they'll just say: he only leaves for €100 millions. Which is just saying, we're not willing to sell, unless you go crazy. Take also contract duration in account, if he's only 1/2 years left on his contract an does not want to sign another, he might be sold under his value (as seen by some).

Comment: You also have to take into account the increase in revenue for clubs over the years. This has increased the clubs spending capacity as well as the selling clubs capacity to refuse offers which aren't 'big' enough. You may call this some kind of football inflation. The prices will just keep on increasing, but I think clubs only pay what they can practically afford, so while it may sound crazy, its not that big an amount.

Comment: @Gaurav What do you think smaller clubs in Scandinavia or Eastern Europe would say abut your "its not that big an amount". I would guess they have an other opinion about. Even the clubs in Germany do (except Bayern Munich)

Comment: @Phab The income disparity between smaller and larger clubs will also continue to increase over year as increase in revenue won't be in same proportion for all... My point is that its not really that baffling when you consider the increase in revenue for top clubs...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a limit on a team's spending in one transfer window?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16342/is-there-a-limit-on-a-teams-spending-in-one-transfer-window)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no FIFA rule that caps the transfer sum.

... and I'll guess we'll see more insane transfers the next years with the Premier League having this absolute ludicrous TV contract.