# Is there a limit on a team's spending in one transfer window?

Tags: football, transfer

Is there any limit that a (football) team can spend in one transfer window? For example, could a team buy Cristiano Ronaldo and Alvaro Morata in a single transfer window?

Comment: can we add about what confederation are we talking about.. there is no rule about it in conmebol (south america)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a rule in football that caps the amount of transfer money paid by a team for a player?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12075/is-there-a-rule-in-football-that-caps-the-amount-of-transfer-money-paid-by-a-tea)

Comment: @Nij, I would add the other question as a duplicate of this one because the accepted answer to that question doesn't even mention Financial Fair Play.

Comment: The other question is on a worldwide basis, so of course it doesn't deal with every possible competition regulations. @gdrt so why would we close it as duplicate of a more limited version?

Comment: @Nij, the context is important. The body of that question *(De Bruyne, Sterling, Juventus, Pogba)* shows that the user was mainly interested in European transfers. The fact that the user doesn't know whether UEFA has its own rules (and thus didn't include UEFA in the question body), doesn't really make the accepted answer complete. And in fact, as you can see, this question also didn't explicitly mention UEFA, but nonetheless I have devoted much of my answer to UEFA's FFP rules, because this question also defined the context around European transfers *(Cristiano Ronaldo, Alvaro Morata)*.

Comment: Or, it's explicitly asking about FIFA and uses the one they happen to know as an example of an outrageously expensive transfer, which happens to be under UEFA as well, which happens to be the context of this question. That's a lot of "happens to be" to justify a duplicate vote at all, let alone from general down to specific.

Comment: @Nij, now that I have explicitly mentioned FIFA's perspective on the transfers (see edit) and based on [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha#147651), could you please tell me which one should we close as a duplicate?

Comment: If you guys want to keep both answers just merge the questions. Otherwise I agree to keep this question and close the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Is there any limit that a (football) team can spend in one transfer window?***

International transfers are governed by FIFA according to [FIFA Regulations on the Status and Transfer of Players](https://www.fifa.com/about-fifa/official-documents/law-regulations/index.html#doctransfersreg). And there's no mention of transfer amount cap in these rules.

But if a team wants to participate in the UEFA competitions, then yes, there is, and this limit is regulated by [UEFA Financial Fair Play Regulations](http://www.uefa.com/community/news/newsid=2064391.html). It started in 2011 and in short, it requires the teams that have qualified for UEFA competitions to prove that:

> ...they do not have overdue payables towards other clubs, their players
>   and social/tax authorities throughout the season. The teams have to
>   prove that they have paid their bills.

Also note that same-association transfers are governed by the association regulations (approved by FIFA) in accordance with FIFA regulations (See [this answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/20000/12991) for further info).

---

*The sections below give some additional overview to UEFA Financial Fair Play Regulations:*

***Are clubs no longer allowed to have losses?***

> Clubs *can spend up to €5m more than they earn* per assessment
>   period (three years). However it can exceed this level to a certain
>   limit, if it is entirely covered by a direct contribution/payment from
>   the club owner(s) or a related party. The limits are *€45m* for assessment periods 2013/14 and 2014/15; and *€30m* for 2015/16, 2016/17 and 2017/18

***What happens if clubs "don't play fair financially"?***

Then [UEFA's Club Financial Control Body](http://www.uefa.org/disciplinary/club-financial-controlling-body/) decides on measures and sanctions:

> - warning
> - reprimand
> - fine
> - deduction of points
> - withholding of revenues from a UEFA competition
> - prohibition on registering new players in UEFA competitions
> - restriction on the number of players that a club may register for participation in UEFA competitions, including a financial limit on the
>     overall aggregate cost of the employee benefits expenses of players
>     registered on the A-list for the purposes of UEFA club competitions
> - disqualification from competitions in progress and/or exclusion from future competitions
> - withdrawal of a title or award

***And the bonus question: "Can a team buy Cristiano Ronaldo and Alvaro Morata in a single transfer window?"***

This question has likely arisen around the rumors of Cristiano Ronaldo and Alvaro Morata's move to Manchester United. According to [Deloitte Football Money League 2017 Report](https://www2.deloitte.com/uk/en/pages/sports-business-group/articles/deloitte-football-money-league.html#), Manchester United had a whooping *€689m* record revenue in the past year, which means given that the total transfer price for 2 aforementioned players doesn't exceed the revenue of an interested club (which doesn't in case of MU), any club that has a revenue proportional to MU can technically afford those transfers. But, of course, those were only the technical details, the guessing part whether or not this will happen is opinion based and these opinions are quantified on betting sites:

- [Cristiano Ronaldo - Club After Summer Transfer Window - Odds](https://www.oddschecker.com/football/football-specials/cristiano-ronaldo/club-after-summer-transfer-window)
- [Alvaro Morata - Club After Summer Transfer Window - Odds](https://www.oddschecker.com/football/football-specials/alvaro-morata/club-after-summer-transfer-window)